# Yum fails with - There are no enabled repos

Tags: linux, redhat

I was trying to install yum on my redhat 7, to install the required packages I used
The error message is 
 'There are no enabled repos.
  Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
  You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable '
How can I fix this??

Comment: Assume "Red Hat Enterprise Linux". (redhat 7 was released year  ~2002). RHEL 7 : If you have no Redhat subscription: No repo´s. (Yum is default, always installed.) ... The old Redhat 7.x : No yum.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.